# How to dismiss a tutorial popover by clicking outside in an Angular JS site?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, popover

I'm testing an Angular site with Protractor and Jasmine framework. 
How can i locate the mouse outside the tutorials popover that is displayed at the login time in order to hide this popover to test the home page?
Here the html code that contain the button of tutorial (previous; next; don't show again) :

```
</div></md-card-content> </md-card><!-- end ngIf: !expandChart --> </div> </div> </div></md-content> </div></div> <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID --> <!--<script>--> <!--!function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){--> <!--(A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),--> <!--r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)--> <!--}(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');--> <!--ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');--> <!--ga('send', 'pageview');--> <!--</script>--> <script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script> <script src="cordova.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>  <div class="introjs-overlay" style="top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;position: fixed;opacity: 0.8;"></div><div class="introjs-helperLayer " style="width: 538px; height:366px; top:64px;left: 195px;"></div><div class="introjs-tooltipReferenceLayer" style="width: 538px; height:366px; top:64px;left: 195px;"><div class="introjs-tooltip" style="left: 546px;"><div class="introjs-tooltiptext">Watchlist view. Swipe the row in the grid to the left to show the delete action.</div><div class="introjs-bullets"><ul><li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="1">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="2">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="3">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="4">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="5">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="6">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="7">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="8">&nbsp;</a></li></ul></div><div class="introjs-progress" style="display: none;"><div class="introjs-progressbar" style="width:12.5%;"></div></div><div class="introjs-arrow left" style="display: inherit;"></div><div class="introjs-tooltipbuttons"><a class="introjs-button introjs-skipbutton" href="javascript:void(0);">Don't show it again!</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="introjs-button introjs-prevbutton introjs-disabled" tabindex="-1">Previous</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="introjs-button introjs-nextbutton">Next</a></div></div></div></body></html>​
```

Comment: The tutorial popover is probably appended to the HTML, right?  You need to identify those elements and tell Protractor to close them (probably in a `beforeAll` block).  If it's like most Modals and you try to click outside, Protractor will throw an error saying "other element (the modal) would receive the click"

Comment: I have added the html for tutorial in the question, the problem i'm having error of jasmine while trying to click into 'don't show again' button

Comment: Well, is there a reason you need to click 'dont show again'?  Because it will show again every time you start up Protractor (because it uses a fresh browser with no cookies)

Comment: Because all home page is under tutorial i can't do anyaction if tutorial popover is opened

Comment: i'm locating it like this  :  element(by.css('.introjs-skipbutton')); is it a correct way ?

Comment: Looks fine.  If not, you can try being more specific `element(by.css('a.introjs-button.introjs-skipbutton'))` or `element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Don't show it again!'))`

Comment: Thanks for your options, but the second one i have already tried some thing similar it didn't pass as if a '(' is missing, i think it happens just because it contain that `'` special character or may be space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111149/discussion-between-emna-and-gunderson).